htlatex causes Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document
I try to compile the following file test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text. 
\end{document}

with htlatex test
but in the resulting log file I read
Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,
(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.

If I do without hyperref, the problem disappears.
I am sure that this problem is quite new:
I always log warnings and it did never occur.
But I use htlatex rarely, so I don't know exactly when the problem came in.
I would like to understand the problem
and I would need a hint to solve.
Maybe one can start explaining what auxhook is used for.

well basically auxhook is used for nothing now and in the next hyperref version I will remove it. For now you should simply ignore the warning.

Hey! quick answer. so the warning is immaterial? Is there a way to suppress? I ask because I have a software detecting warnings.. so ignoring is not so easy ;-)

you can suppress the loading with \makeatletter\disable@package@load{auxhook}{}\makeatother.

seems to work fine.. but ... later on I use package transparent
and with that line, it does not work any more.
Maybe I shall disable before loading hyperref and then enable again. ? Possible?

I found myself: \makeatletter\reenable@package@load{auxhook}\makeatother
So the solution is to disable loading auxhook before loading hyperref and to reenable after loading.

You should be loading hyperref last except for stuff you know definitely needs to come later. That said, I don't get an error if I add transparent regardless of order.

Well yes, transparent uses auxhook

@UlrikeFischer: Could you formulate an answer so that I have something to accept.
